# Go GAE Using LoginURLFederated function returns API error 2 (user: NOT_ALLOWED)

Tags: google-app-engine, go, oauth-2.0, openid, federated-identity

I am trying to use LoginURLFederated for logging users in. My code is as follows:-

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
u, _ := user.CurrentOAuth(c, "")

if u == nil {

    if loginUrl, err := user.LoginURLFederated(c, "/webservice/uid-test", "gmail.com"); err != nil {

        http.Error(w, "here1"+err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    } else {

        http.Redirect(w, r, loginUrl, http.StatusFound)
        return
    }

}
```

I got this error

```
here1API error 2 (user: NOT_ALLOWED)
```

When I change from *LoginURLFederated* to *LoginURL* function, it worked fine. What did I miss? I tried to use *user.Current(c)* as well, however, I didn't work either.

The reason I am doing this is because I am trying to verify the idToken that is being sent from an android app that uses google sign-in api for signing in. Google sign in api implements oauth2 standard and generate idToken for other app: in this case, my web app written in Go running on GAE, to use the idToken to verify the signed in user. More information about android google sign in is here *https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#send-the-id-token-to-your-server*

However, I didn't realize that Google ID that I received from calling [user.LoginURL(c)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/) in Go web app on GAE was different from the sub value (ID) received from calling Google idToken endpoint here

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=value
```

Then I realized that the IDs were generated by two different Google endpoints. I decided to use Google federated login function on the web app side to match the ID received from

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=value
```

since federated login implements openid (oauth) but I am receiving an unknown error **API error 2 (user: NOT_ALLOWED)**

Am I doing things right? Can federated login generate the identical id with the sub value (id) sent from google idToken endpoint?

Comment: Based on the error you're receiving I would guess everything worked and you simply did not pass valid creds to the server. If the request itself were bad I'd expect a different error. Whatever credentials you're attempting to use for Federated Auth aren't accepted by the server. Verify what it's expecting and what gets sent.

Comment: Do you know where can I pass the credential to the federated login function?

Comment: I went to GAE console and found that there was no federated login option: just Google User and App Domain options are available.

Comment: So are you attempting to do OAuth with a users gmail/google creds? I would guess that's what is meant by Google User.

Comment: Yes, I am. Currently I am using user.LoginURL function but I want to switch to user.LoginURLFederated function to get the sub ID that is identical with the one from Google sign-in for Android which implements oauth2.

Comment: Can you update your question with your imports and/or link to the packages docs? I'll need to take a look at them to help any further.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just updated the question.